# Stormpath A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is tru

Tags: angularjs, express, stormpath

I'm using Stormpath and I'd like to separate my API from the client code (Angular, using Stormpath's angular-sdk). This means the API will be on a different sub-domain than the client. As soon as I did this, I hit the error;

`A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true`

I fixed this by adding the specific domains to my express CORS configuration by setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, but now the API just won't respond to hits from the browser.

So I'm a little confused, I'd prefer the API to be open but still authenticate using Stormpath but maybe thats not possible?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: https://stormpath.com/blog/angularjs-spring-boot-tutorial
It uses Spring so YMMV, but could still be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Stormpath AngularJS SDK has an example application that shows you how to get CORS working with AngularJS and Express.

https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs/tree/master/example/cors-app

The code you're looking for is in `server.js`, [starting at line 22](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs/blob/master/example/cors-app/server.js#L22).

```
var cors = require('cors');
...
/*
  The apiService is your API that you want to protect with
  Stormpath.  We use the CORS module to whitelist the website
  domain, thus allowing it to communicate with the API domain
 */

var apiService = express();

apiService.use(cors({
  origin: websiteDomain,
  credentials: true
}));

apiService.use(stormpath.init(apiService,{ }));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!